# SyntaxError: unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')' in long If condition

Tags: ruby

This is my `if` condition:

```
if (!href.value.include? "http://" || !href.value.include? "https://" || !href.value.include? "www" && href.value.include? ".htm")
```

This is the error message:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'
... "www" && href.value.include? ".htm")
```

However, each of those conditions work individually:

```
> hrefs.first.value
=> "AccountantBocaRaton.html"
> hrefs.first.value.include? "http://"
=> false
> hrefs.first.value.include? "https://"
=> false
> hrefs.first.value.include? "wwww"
=> false
> hrefs.first.value.include? ".html"
=> true
> hrefs.first.value.include? ".htm"
=> true
```

What could be causing this?

**Edit 1**

I also tried splitting it up, putting parens around all the `||` conditions and around the `&&` conditions and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad:

```
'asd'.include? 'a' && 'asd'.include 's'

SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting end-of-input
'asd'.include? 'a' && 'asd'.include? 's'
```

Good:

```
'asd'.include?('a') && 'asd'.include?('s')
```

The `&&` is confusing the parser. And with good reason since that's kind of of ambiguous.

Is that:

```
!href.value.include?("www" && href.value.include?(".htm"))
```

Or what you probably meant:

```
!href.value.include?("www") && href.value.include?(".htm")
```

So add some parens and it should be ok.

Comment: Can also use the looser `and`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Alex Wayne will fix the issue and explains why the `SyntaxError` is thrown, but a better solution IMO is, instead of having the giant `if` statement, to use a regular expression:

```
web_regex = /http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www|htm/
if !(href.value =~ web_regex)
  #rest of code here
end
```

`=~` will return `0`(truthy) or `nil` (falsey). I'm sure there are other tweaks on the regex route, but what I have above is concise and easier to maintain than the giant `if` statement.

Comment: You can use `%r[ ... ]` when the `/.../` syntax conflicts with slashes in the expression. That avoids a lot of ugly escaping. Also `unless href.value.match(web_regex)` is perhaps more readable than the often mysterious `=~` operator from Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from @Alex Wayne's answer. One way to write this is like below(Easier on the eyes).

```
    str = "https://wwww.AccountantBocaRaton.html" ; 
    if !(str.include?("http://") 
         || str.include?("https://") 
         || str.include?("www")) 
         && (str.include?(".htm")) 
      puts true 

    else 
      puts false 
    end 

    returns=> false
```

*****Positive test case:*****

```
   str = "AccountantBocaRaton.html"
    if !(str.include?("http://") 
         || str.include?("https://") 
         || str.include?("www")) 
         && (str.include?(".htm")) 
      puts true 

    else 
      puts false 
    end 

    returns=> true
```

Quick test via irb :

```
irb(main):024:0> str = "AccountantBocaRaton.html" ; if !(str.include?("http://") || str.include?("https://") || str.include?("www")) && (str.include?(".htm")); puts true ; else puts false  ; end 
true
```

Comment: What is with those semi-colons?

Comment: wrote it as a oneliner " leftovers". Will remove them now.